# How can I create safe per-web-request transaction in .net's MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, transactions, httpwebrequest, transactionscope

I need to be all my entire application transactional in its every web request it processes.

I need the transaction to start and, if there was no exceptions in controllers, commit it. Otherwise, rollback.

So far, I have the following implementation:

- First, I create transaction on controller as a dependency.
- Then, I do my controller/service/repositories/other stuff work.
- And finally, the main abstract controller class executes its `OnActionExecuted` method, where I either commit it or I don't.

Here goes the list of technologies that I use:

- MVC 4
- Ninject
- Automapper
- Service pattern

**Now**, what I want to know is what about the **deadlocks**? What will happen when two web requests will be **simultaneously** processed, and besides they will acquire the right to work with two repositories (which are linked to the theirs `DataContext` instances), and which means, **two tables** in the database?

For example: one request at first wants to read table `Table1` and then `Table2`, in meantime the other request wants to work with `Table2` and then with `Table1`.

What should I do?

Comment: I will answer as a comment, because my answer's scope (and I think your question's) require much more than a SO answer. IMO you need to separate your presentation concerns from your "domain" (or business logic). That architecture gives you two advantages: a) the ability to orchestrate the execution of individual logical subcomponents and their participation (or not) in a MS-controlled transaction,and b) code infrastructure that lends itself much better to implementing some form of custom transaction or queuing,if out-of-the box tools and best-practices aren't enough due to your app's specifics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have realized some solutions to the question:

- The first one is to have a list of all the tables and access them by that list. Thus, the exampled `Table2` will never be accessed before `Table1` if both are required by the context, and the deadlock will not happen.
- The second is to create a lazy-IO system which tracks all the necessary changes (like adding an item, retriving its id and using it somewhere else). But it seems quite difficult to build.
- Another approach is to create application-level locks on every database request at its start and release it at the end. The solution is completely deadlock-free, however it is usable only on low-load systems.

Answer (score 2):

you can handle start and stop of transaction for call to DB please check this

[How to prevent EntityFramework deadlock when concurrently running these two statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097179/how-to-prevent-entityframework-deadlock-when-concurrently-running-these-two-stat)

hope this help

Comment: Yes I can but the main reason I have transferred this option to semi-automatic flow is I dont want to manually each time open and close the transaction.

Comment: Interesting question, like to see a good answer for this with the provided technologies you use.

Comment: I love you thinking about this problem. I have gotten some thing like this, and spent a few days to resolving it. The problem because, we need an unit of work for this case, but in EF we already has it in DataContext, so we have to implement the DataContext with implementing IDisposable interface. Then after we wrap it in the context scope like using keyword. and we can release the connection that associate with it after calling completed.