# Linq to Entities Sometimes Inserting Duplicate Entries Into Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

The below code is used to add a line to the database or update the line that is already there.

```
IEnumerable<Guid> fieldIds = glen.ComplianceField.Select(field => field.id);
ComplianceData data;
foreach (Guid fieldId in fieldIds)
{
    if (!checkEntity(fieldId, Extra.grn))
    {
        if (collection[fieldId.ToString()] != null)
        {
            if (glen.ComplianceData.Where(compData => (compData.fieldId == fieldId) && (compData.grn == Extra.grn)).Count() == 0)
            {
                data = new ComplianceData();
                glen.ComplianceData.Add(data);
            }
            else
                data = glen.ComplianceData.First(compData => (compData.fieldId == fieldId) && (compData.grn == Extra.grn));
            data.fieldId = fieldId;
            data.grn = Extra.grn;
            data.value = collection[fieldId.ToString()];
        }
    }
}
glen.SaveChanges();
```

However sometimes (I'm suspecting if the user clicks a submit button multiple times) the row is duplicated in the database (multiple times if the server is being particularly slow).  This problem only occurs when first creating the entry, after that the first entry will be updated as expected.

I have tried using the ChangeTracker property of the context but that doesn't work I suspect because the glen context is a different object in each successive request.  Is there a way to either lock the database table while the Action is being carried out or prevent the Action carrying out the database updates if the same request has just been made?

Comment: If that snippet runs from different thread you will get such behavior. You must synchronize you code. Also, you must add some integrity constraints to you database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do this using `System.Transactions` (I had to add a new reference to to access it).  My final snippet is -

```
IEnumerable<Guid> fieldIds = glen.ComplianceField.Select(field => field.id);
ComplianceData data;
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable}))
        {
            foreach (Guid fieldId in fieldIds)
            {
                if (collection[fieldId.ToString()] != null)
                {
                    if (glen.ComplianceData.Where(compData => (compData.fieldId == fieldId) && (compData.grn == Extra.grn)).Count() == 0)
                    {
                        data = new ComplianceData();
                        glen.ComplianceData.Add(data);
                    }
                    else
                        data = glen.ComplianceData.First(compData => (compData.fieldId == fieldId) && (compData.grn == Extra.grn));
                        data.fieldId = fieldId;
                        data.grn = Extra.grn;
                        data.value = collection[fieldId.ToString()];
                }
            }
            glen.SaveChanges();
            scope.Complete();
        }
```

Thanks in part to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13097278/1173776

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect it is due to a multiple submit click of a button then you can take various steps to stop this such as disabling the button as soon as it has been activated. You should also put in some server side checking to make sure multiple requests haven't come through.

Comment: I realise already that I could prevent this client side however I am looking for a way as you say to check multiple requests haven't come through.  I will update my question to reflect this.